# Java Linked List Stack push function not changing the data

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I cannot change the parameters of the function, or the Node constructor. When I call the push function – `push(T element1)` – and then call it again with a different element – `push(T element2)` – it doesn't end up changing the data of the node at all and just gives it the `element1` data.

```
 public void push(T element) {
  /* YOUR CODE HERE */
     Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(element, top);
     if(isEmpty()) {
         top = bottom = newNode;
         System.out.println("Stack is empty");
     }
     newNode.setData(element);
     newNode.setLink(top);
     top = newNode;
     count++;
     return;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with Your code:

```
Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(element, top);
```

You pass data and nextNode in the constructor, so You don't have to set them further in code.

You also don't have to use `return;` at the end of the void methods.

Moreover, in a LinkedList for stack implementation You most probably dont need bottom, it should be Singly LinkedList.

```
 public void push(T element) {
     Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(element, top);
     top = newNode;

     count++;
 }
```

This should be the working code example.

Here is a good solution for Your problem, You could take inspiration from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-a-stack-using-singly-linked-list/